# How to make button with image and determine CGSize in sprite kit swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite

How can I create a button with an image so I can still decided the CGSize myself. Right now I can only do this.

```
let playNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44))
    playNode.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    playNode.name = "play"
    addChild(playNode)
```

I would like to replace the red color with an actual image. So far I haven't found a way how to actual create a button with an image AND decide its CGSize. I do know how to create a button just with an image, but I can't determine its CGSize then. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `size` property of your node after you've set the image. Like that:

```
let playNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImage")

//Set it after you've set the image.
playNode.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)

playNode.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
playNode.name = "play"
addChild(playNode)
```